# Do not retrieve correct hexa decimal value from MySql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, hex

I'm trying to add value to sp1 table by using following procedure.
but it do not retrieve correct hexa decimal values.

```
create table sp1(
id varchar(10),
txt varchar(10)
);


create procedure sp_ins1(p varchar(10))
BEGIN
set @x = char_length(p);
set @y = binary(p);
insert into sp1(id,txt)
    values(@x,@y);
END;
```

Add values to table by calling following function.

```
call sp_ins1(4);
call sp_ins1(13);
call sp_ins1(45);

select * from sp1\g
```

This is the result

```
+------+----------+
| id   | txt      |
+------+----------+
| 1    | 34       |
| 2    | 3133     |
| 2    | 3435     |
| 4    | 36373537 |
| 1    | 31       |
+------+----------+
```

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand the problem. In addition `sp_ins7` != `sp_ins1`.

Try:

```sql
mysql> SELECT
    ->   CHAR_LENGTH('4') `id`,
    ->   BINARY('4') `txt_BIN`,
    ->   HEX('4') `txt_HEX`
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT
    ->   CHAR_LENGTH('13') `id`,
    ->   BINARY('13') `txt_BIN`,
    ->   HEX('13') `txt_HEX`
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT
    ->   CHAR_LENGTH('45') `id`,
    ->   BINARY('45') `txt_BIN`,
    ->   HEX('45') `txt_HEX`
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT
    ->   CHAR_LENGTH('6757') `id`,
    ->   BINARY('6757') `txt_BIN`,
    ->   HEX('6757') `txt_HEX`
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT
    ->   CHAR_LENGTH('1') `id`,
    ->   BINARY('1') `txt_BIN`,
    ->   HEX('1') `txt_HEX`;
+----+---------+----------+
| id | txt_BIN | txt_HEX  |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 | 4       | 34       |
|  2 | 13      | 3133     |
|  2 | 45      | 3435     |
|  4 | 6757    | 36373537 |
|  1 | 1       | 31       |
+----+---------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [12.5 String Functions::HEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_hex).

Comment: Oops! it should be sp_ins1. Its a mistake. but result is correct. The problem is why come 3 before every hex value?